# Unable to display Toolbar items in a NavigationController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display toolbar items at the bottom of TableViewController which is inside a Navigation Controller. I’ve written this code in Swift.

I've used Xcode default master-detail template to create the project and written the below code in ViewDidLoad method of MasterTableViewController.

**Please help me to fix the issue.**

Please find below code snippet.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.addToolBar();
}


func addToolBar ()->Void {

        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false

        var toolBarItems = NSMutableArray()

        var systemButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBarItems.addObject(systemButton1)

        var systemButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBarItems.addObject(systemButton2)

        var systemButton3 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Trash, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBarItems.addObject(systemButton3)

        self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
        self.setToolbarItems(toolbarItems, animated: true)
        //self.navigationController?.toolbarItems = toolbarItems;

    }
```

But Interestingly, the same code written in Objective-C works and shows the toolbar at the bottom with two items

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    [self addToolbar];
}

-(void) addToolbar
{
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;

    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:item1];

    UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:item2];

    UIBarButtonItem *item3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:nil action:nil];
    [items addObject:item3];


    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
//    self.navigationController.toolbarItems = items;
//    
    [self setToolbarItems:items animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use a name that's not the same (except for capitalization) as a native property of the view controller. Your typo (pointed out in Matthias's answer) wasn't caught by the compiler because of this.

Answer (score 2):

You have a tiny typo in your code. I highlighted the difference for you:

```
var toolBarItems = NSMutableArray()
//      ^
// [...]
self.setToolbarItems(toolbarItems, animated: true)
//                       ^
```

Your code does basically this (with an animation):

```
self.toolbarItems = self.toolbarItems
```

Your set the toolbarItems array to the current toolbarItems array, which is empty.

when you use `self.setToolbarItems(toolBarItems, animated: true)` it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Using NSMutableArray gave me error, the below code worked for me

```
func setUpToolbar(){

    var toolBarItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    let systemButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBarItems.append(systemButton1)

    let systemButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBarItems.append(systemButton2)

    let systemButton3 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Trash, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBarItems.append(systemButton3)

    self.setToolbarItems(toolBarItems, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
}
```